# Virtualbox NAT port forwarding not working

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, port-forwarding, nat

I am trying to forward Growl messages from my virtualbox windows guest to the growl notifier instance on my windows host.

Growl runs on port 23053. Here is my network configuration.

[image: NAT TCP, UDP ports 23053 forwarded to 23053]

But I'm not receiving any messages on the host. I have confirmed that if I set up growl notifier in my guest VM it works just fine so I'm quite sure the issue is port forwarding.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: VBox NAT port forwarding is usually host -> guest, not guest -> host. the guest should always be able to contact the host, just not the other way around. Also, I don't recommend you use rules like these with no IP/Interface designations, but that has no impact either way, since you are sending from within the NAT to the outside (the host).

Comment: Thanks Frank, so I could of course put an IP address in there, but that would switch every time I visit a coffee shop - what I would like is for any requests to `localhost:23053` on the guest to be passed right through to the host

Comment: well, either way, you shouldn't use a NAT port forard rule in this circumstance, since you are calling out of the NAT network, not calling into it. the issue here seems to be that the hosts NIC is DHCP and its address may change, so you don;t have a consistent value to use to connect to the host. you could try using Bridged or Host-Only networking, but you would have to be careful with teh firewalling so as not to expose services on your VM to the LAN, wherever it may be at the moment.

Comment: it sounds like you want a tunneling protocol. can you install ssh on the host, and tunnel from vm:23053 to host:23053?

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas I have no idea how that works (I'm on the developer side not the sysadmin side) but I'll look into it

Comment: Is the port open in the VM? Try  `nmap -sT -O localhost`. You could also try bridged networking, which will assign the VM its own IP address.